# Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Cosmos.CosmosCache not working for MSAL tokens

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-ad-msal

I'm getting the below error. I am trying to configure Cosmos as a Cache for MSAL.

> The input ttl 'null' is invalid. Ensure to provide a nonzero positive
> integer less than or equal to '2147483647', or '-1' which means never
> expire.

Full error:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 Substatus: 0 Reason: (Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BadRequestException: Message: {"Errors":["The input ttl 'null' is invalid. Ensure to provide a nonzero positive integer less than or equal to '2147483647', or '-1' which means never expire."]}ActivityId: ee10ce6b-bc78-4b64-a874-d464c2db1712, Request URI: /apps/9610078f-64d0-4c3a-8746-3fe6f02be78f/services/c5612d1f-a656-4cf5-99c4-0b1f50b5a1e2/partitions/2107c960-b060-49d1-8e03-3939fc11bb8a/replicas/132575139009767109p/, RequestStats: RequestStartTime: 2021-02-15T10:10:06.2053638Z, RequestEndTime: 2021-02-15T10:10:06.3804622Z, Number of regions attempted:1ResponseTime: 2021-02-15T10:10:06.3804622Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-westeurope1-fd56.documents.azure.com:14056/apps/9610078f-64d0-4c3a-8746-3fe6f02be78f/services/c5612d1f-a656-4cf5-99c4-0b1f50b5a1e2/partitions/2107c960-b060-49d1-8e03-3939fc11bb8a/replicas/132575139009767109p/, LSN: 3, GlobalCommittedLsn: 3, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 400, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 2.38, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#3, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Upsert, SDK: Windows/10.0.19042 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.4.2 at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.TransportClient.ThrowServerException(String resourceAddress, StoreResponse storeResponse, Uri physicalAddress, Guid activityId, DocumentServiceRequest request) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Rntbd.TransportClient.<InvokeStoreAsync>d__8.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ConsistencyWriter.<WritePrivateAsync>d__17.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility1.d__5.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility1.<ExecuteRetryAsync>d__5.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ConsistencyWriter.<WriteAsync>d__16.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<<InvokeAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestRetryUtility.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__22.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestRetryUtility.d__22.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreClient.<ProcessMessageAsync>d__19.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServerStoreModel.<ProcessMessageAsync>d__15.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler.<ProcessUpsertAsync>d__5.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler.<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext()).
```

This code seems to work:

```
 public IConfidentialClientApplication BuildApp()
    {
        // The application which retreives the auth token must also use the same client id and redirect url when requesting the token. The auth token from the response is then passed to the AquireTokenByAuthorisationCode method below. 
        IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("XXX")
            .WithRedirectUri("XXX")
            .WithClientSecret("XXX")
            .WithTenantId("XXX")
            .Build();

        IMsalTokenCacheProvider cosmosTokenCacheProvider = CreateCosmosTokenCacheSerialiser();
        Task.Run(() => cosmosTokenCacheProvider.InitializeAsync(app.UserTokenCache)).Wait();

        return app;
    }

private static IMsalTokenCacheProvider CreateCosmosTokenCacheSerialiser()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddDistributedTokenCaches();
        services.AddCosmosCache((CosmosCacheOptions cacheOptions) =>
        {
            cacheOptions.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XXX"];
            cacheOptions.ContainerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XXX"];
            cacheOptions.CreateIfNotExists = true;
            cacheOptions.ClientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(cosmosConnectionString);
            //cacheOptions.DefaultTimeToLiveInMs = 100000;
        });

        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        IMsalTokenCacheProvider msalTokenCacheProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMsalTokenCacheProvider>();

        return msalTokenCacheProvider;
    }
```

But the flow fails when running this:

```
       public async Task AquireTokenByAuthorisationCode(IEnumerable<string> scopes, string authorisationCode)
    {


        var authenticationResult = await _confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authorisationCode).ExecuteAsync();
    }
```

I have tried various combinations of setting cacheOptions.DefaultTimeToLiveInMs and tried turning ttl on and off at the Cosmos container level.

Am I misconfiguring something or is this an issue?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Which version of the Caching library are you using?

Comment: Reference GitHub issue: https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Cosmos/issues/36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the error trace, the version you are using seems old: `Windows/10.0.19042 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.4.2`.

Current Nuget package ([preview-5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Cosmos/1.0.0-preview5)) requires SDK >= 3.11.0.

Could you please try and update the Nuget package to the latest preview-5 version?